# String values are persisted with double quotes in table using Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, jersey

We are using Spring JPA with MySQL. While inserting values into the table, the string values are inserted with double quotes. Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

We are using MySQL 8, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar and Java 11.

```
@Override
public Response createNamespace(Namespace namespaceDto) throws AdminException {
    try {
        com.###.tcp.ens.adminservice.entity.Namespace namespace = 
                                       new com.###.tcp.ens.adminservice.entity.Namespace();
        namespace.setNamespace(namespaceDto.getNameSpace());
        namespace.setAssociatedAppTrn(namespaceDto.getAssociatedAppTrn());
        namespace.setAdmins(namespaceDto.getAdminUser());
        if (namespaceRepository.findByNamespace(namespaceDto.getNameSpace()).isPresent()) {
            return AdminHelper.exceptionHandler(new Exception(),
                                                HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                                                AdminStatus.NAMESPACE_EXISTS,
                                                AdminStatus.NAMESPACE_EXISTS.message());
        } else {
            namespaceRepository.save(namespace);
            return Response.status(HttpStatus.CREATED.value()).entity(namespace).build();
        }
    } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException exception) {
        return AdminHelper.exceptionHandler(exception, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                                            AdminStatus.NAMESPACE_CREATE_FAILED,
                                            AdminStatus.NAMESPACE_CREATE_FAILED.message());
    }
}
```

[image]

Expected output is :

'58', 'com.test.tcp3', 'some text5,some text6'

Actual output is :

'57', '\"com.test.tcp3\"', '\"some text5,some text6\"'

Comment: where is this *output* coming from?

Comment: More likely, it is nothing to do with Spring JPA and MySql. The values in your namespaceDto  or code that your are using to print output, has escaped double quote strings.

Comment: check the values in your namespaceDto

Comment: @ScaryWombat : I just included the output for reference. Please check the table screenshot at the end of the question. You can see the fields 'namespace' and 'publisher_app_trn' having values enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: @Adi  It has nothing to do with the values in namespaceDto. I even tried hardcoding a string value in the Entity class setter but still it inserts data into table with double quotes.

Comment: @VincentMarian I have the same problem. Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @MateuszSobczak We started coding from scratch again and we did not get this issue afterwards. Not sure what was the mistake we did previously. Sorry I could not help you out much on this.